# Cannot gather Google PING data with tcpdump command

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, tcpdump

I am baffled at this point following a Linux course on Udemy.
The command I am using in CentOS7 is:

```
tcpdump -i enp0s3 | grep 216.25.212.58
```

`216.25.212.58` is the IP that is shown when I use the command:

```
ping www.google.com
```

I am using a virtual machine on Oracle VM and I am expecting some ICMP requests since I have the pinger open on another duplicate session but the command gets stuck and does not return anything like it does on the lecture.

[image: Consoles]

Can anybody tell me what the issue might be and how to get some returning data?

---

In this case, to look at any icmp dumps,

I changed the command to simply:

```
tcpdump -i enp0s3 icmp
```

And now it returns:

```
[root@mycentos7vm ~]# tcpdump -i enp0s3 icmp

tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp0s3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
06:49:19.326067 IP mycentos7vm > lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 21856, seq 1, length 64
06:49:19.339880 IP lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net > mycentos7vm: ICMP echo reply, id 21856, seq 1, length 64
06:49:20.328544 IP mycentos7vm > lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 21856, seq 2, length 64
06:49:20.341887 IP lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net > mycentos7vm: ICMP echo reply, id 21856, seq 2, length 64
06:49:21.330406 IP mycentos7vm > lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 21856, seq 3, length 64
06:49:21.340807 IP lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net > mycentos7vm: ICMP echo reply, id 21856, seq 3, length 64
06:49:22.332153 IP mycentos7vm > lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 21856, seq 4, length 64
06:49:22.342174 IP lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net > mycentos7vm: ICMP echo reply, id 21856, seq 4, length 64
06:49:23.333899 IP mycentos7vm > lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 21856, seq 5, length 64
06:49:23.352133 IP lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net > mycentos7vm: ICMP echo reply, id 21856, seq 5, length 64
```

This was returned after the duplication session is pinging [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).

```
[root@mycentos7vm ~]# ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (142.250.187.196) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.187.196): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=12.6 ms
64 bytes from lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.187.196): icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=13.6 ms
64 bytes from lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.187.196): icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=9.85 ms
64 bytes from lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.187.196): icmp_seq=4 ttl=117 time=12.3 ms
64 bytes from lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.187.196): icmp_seq=5 ttl=117 time=10.1 ms
```

My question is: why doesn't this tcp command return anything?

```
tcpdump -i enp0s3 | grep 142.250.187.196
```

Newbie here: does it have something with google not revealing their IPs during a tcpdump?

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Aren't you running the ping and the tcpdump on two completely different VMs?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com//help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: why doesn't this tcp command return anything?
>
> ```
> tcpdump -i enp0s3 | grep 142.250.187.196
> ```

Because *there is no mention* of "142.250.187.196" in tcpdump's output, as you can see for yourself.

Instead, the packets are shown by tcpdump as coming from "lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net", which is the "reverse DNS" lookup of 142.250.187.196.

grep only deals with text, and it only searches for plain text matches; it does not try to understand domains or IP addresses (or the relationship between the two). If tcpdump did not *output* some text in the first place, grep will not find it out of thin air.

> Newbie here: does it have something with google not revealing their IPs during a tcpdump?

No, Google cannot "not reveal their IPs". The IP addresses are always known, because IP packet delivery always uses the addresses (not domain names); the OS couldn't send the packets if it didn't know the address.

What you're seeing is a lookup done in the opposite direction – *from* an already known IP address to the name. The tcpdump tool is performing a "[reverse DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup)" lookup of the IP addresses to their corresponding domain names, and deliberately printing only those names instead of the raw addresses (as the reverse-DNS labels are supposed to be more descriptive).

So in short, it's mostly tcpdump's decision to omit the address from its output – and again, grep cannot find text if that text doesn't exist in its input.

You can use the `-n` tcpdump option to disable reverse-DNS lookups and make it always print the raw IP addresses. (This will also generally make things faster, as rDNS queries can sometimes be slow.)

```
tcpdump -n -i enp0s3 | grep ...
```

But what you *actually* should've done is use a [tcpdump capture filter](https://packetlife.net/media/library/12/tcpdump.pdf) instead of text-based grep, and let tcpdump itself match the IP addresses before producing the output:

```
tcpdump -i enp0s3 "host 142.250.187.196"
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, to look at any icmp dumps,

I changed the command to simply:

### tcpdump -i enp0s3 icmp

And now it returns:
[root@mycentos7vm ~]# tcpdump -i enp0s3 icmp

tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp0s3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
06:49:19.326067 IP mycentos7vm > lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 21856, seq 1, length 64
06:49:19.339880 IP lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net > mycentos7vm: ICMP echo reply, id 21856, seq 1, length 64
06:49:20.328544 IP mycentos7vm > lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 21856, seq 2, length 64
06:49:20.341887 IP lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net > mycentos7vm: ICMP echo reply, id 21856, seq 2, length 64
06:49:21.330406 IP mycentos7vm > lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 21856, seq 3, length 64
06:49:21.340807 IP lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net > mycentos7vm: ICMP echo reply, id 21856, seq 3, length 64
06:49:22.332153 IP mycentos7vm > lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 21856, seq 4, length 64
06:49:22.342174 IP lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net > mycentos7vm: ICMP echo reply, id 21856, seq 4, length 64
06:49:23.333899 IP mycentos7vm > lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 21856, seq 5, length 64
06:49:23.352133 IP lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net > mycentos7vm: ICMP echo reply, id 21856, seq 5, length 64

This was returned after the duplication session is pinging [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).

[root@mycentos7vm ~]# ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

PING [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) (142.250.187.196) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.187.196): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=12.6 ms

64 bytes from lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.187.196): icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=13.6 ms

64 bytes from lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.187.196): icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=9.85 ms

64 bytes from lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.187.196): icmp_seq=4 ttl=117 time=12.3 ms

64 bytes from lhr25s33-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.187.196): icmp_seq=5 ttl=117 time=10.1 ms

My question is: why doesn't this tcp command return anything?

### tcpdump -i enp0s3 | grep 142.250.187.196

Newbie here: does it have something with google not revealing their IPs during a tcpdump?

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com//help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.